# Creating MySQL 5.0 query/view with one-to-many relationships

Tags: mysql, json, pdo

I have a MySQL 5.0 database with the following schema:

[image: Database schema]

I'm using it in a web application making ajax calls to server/words, where I query the database using PDO and return json. My goal here is to get resulting json like this:

```js
[ //array of words
{
"word": "...",
"fonetics": "...",
...
"meanigngs":[] // array of meanings (objects)
"inflections":[] // array of inflections
"examples":[]
},
...
]
```

One way to achive this is to query database multiple times, each for every table, and then work on json structure in php. I know it's not very good, but I'm mostly front-end guy, and I don't know much about MySQL.
I was also thinking about creating a view constituting of required tables.

Could you guide me to best solution or perhaps even write a piece of mysql that creates view/gets required data out of database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need all the data, and want it structured in an object hierarchy the way you describe, then doing so at the application level is probably really your best option. Make sure to sort the tables by `word_id` so that you can grab the values for your sub-arrays from consecutive rows in your query results.

Alternatives would include:

- Query the database once for every sub-array. This would make building the structure a lot easier, and might reduce memory consumption in the client, but it would cause a much larger number of queries. If you do this, then definitely go for prepared statements!
- Create one big view by joining tables. This would massively duplicate data, in particular as you'd include the full cross product between rather unrelated tables, e.g. every combination between a meaning and an inflection and so on. Definitely not the route to take here.